# Google charts visualization instantiateproblem Dashboard

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Im trying to create a Dashboard for my webpage but I cant instantiate the Dashboard.

```
var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById("marketareas_div"));
```

and the apicall:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src='https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={"modules":[{"name":"visualization","version":"1.1","packages":["corechart"]}]}'/>
```

Problem: "google.visualization.Dashboard is not a constructor".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of you need to close that script-tag otherwise the page will break in some browsers.

The problem seems to be that there is no Dashboard-object when you include the script with package corechart from google. Change it to controls which includes Dashboard.

More info:
http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls.html

Comment: Thx for the help. The feeling I get from you is that you are polite computerguy.

Answer (score 2):

Is your API correctly loaded ?

Looking at the google's [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/loader/#AutoLoading), your auto-loading url is not correct, it should be encoded:

This:

> {"modules":[{"name":"search","version":"1.0","language":"en"},{"name":"maps","version":"2.x"},{"name":"elements","version":"1.0","packages":["localsearch"]}]}

becomes this:

> %7B%22modules%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22search%22%2C%22version%22%3A%221.0%22%2C%22language%22%3A%22en%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22maps%22%2C%22version%22%3A%222.X%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22elements%22%2C%22version%22%3A%221.0%22%2C%22packages%22%3A%5B%22localsearch%22%5D%7D%5D%7D

to be called like this:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload=%7B%22modules%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22search%22%2C%22version%22%3A%221.0%22%2C%22language%22%3A%22en%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22maps%22%2C%22version%22%3A%222.X%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22elements%22%2C%22version%22%3A%221.0%22%2C%22packages%22%3A%5B%22localsearch%22%5D%7D%5D%7D&key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY"></script>
```

They actually **don't recommend** using this way for loading.

> **Warning!** This advanced feature can be difficult to implement,
>   depending on the exact situation. Therefore, we recommend that you
>   consider auto-loading only in specific instances where reducing
>   latency is crucial.

Try using a more simple loading like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1.1");
    ...
</script>
```